# Get 2nd to last and last values and output

Tags: string, bash

I have a command Im running through bash, `$CI_PROJECT_PATH`, this value is any one of the following strings where string can include `1:M` subdirectories... like:

```
 - company/ent/one/project/test-projects/webgoat
 - company/ent/one/project/test-projects/path/here/webgoat
 - company/ent/one/project/test-projects/path/here/another-path/one/webgoat
```

How can I write a little bash routine to pluck always the second and last directories? like:

```
 - test-projects/webgoat
 - here/webgoat
 - one/webgoat
```

I did a little research and it appears I could use the `cut` operator but from my research it doesnt work with many subdirs.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: You can use `grep -o` with a regular expression that matches the last two parts of the pathname.

Comment: `cut` doesn't have any way to count from the end, only from the beginning.

Comment: You could also use `awk` with the field separator set to `/`, and print `$(NF-1)` and `$NF`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F\/ '{ print $(NF-1)"/"$NF }' <<< "$CI_PROJECT_PATH"
```

Redirect the variable back into awk. Set the field separator to "/" and then print the last but one field ($(NF-1)) followed by "/" and the last field ($NF)